# mongoose document.validate throws RangeError after updating from 4.4x to ^4.5.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I recently updated mongoose to 4.5.1 or anything above that really. Document.validate now throws "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" This happens when my schema has an embedded document array. Though if the array is empty the validation is successful. This is true for all my schemas.

**Here is an example of my code**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      roles: { type: [userRoleSchema]: default [] }
})

var userRoleSchema = new Schema({
      type: { type: String, required: true },
      organization: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'organization', required: false },
})

// Later when I call this
userDocument.validate((err) => { /* I don't even end up here */ })
```

I've testet my code on 4.4.1 and 4.4.2 and 4.5.0 and I have no problem there. But I really need to use 4.5.1 or higher and that's when I get this problem. I've looked for hours but haven't found anyone with this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it changing the schema type to Schema.Types.Mixed for all my embedded array schemes. The drawback is that I no longer have validation for these schema but it solved the problem at least.